# Can we import file before form submit in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

Can we have spring ability to upload a file and keep the reference of it in form submit?

Means I want to have the functionality to submit the form in two steps:

1. In the first step upload a file of my page and want to see uploaded file on UI(it is my application requirement).
2. In the second step, I want to submit the form with the uploaded file path.

I have this functionality with single step using spring and angular js.

Comment: what is the purpose for that requirement? is that strict?

Comment: Actually, I have to create a application in which if I uploaded any file (like json, sql or shell script file) from UI, then before form submit I can see and edit this file in my inbuilt editor to make any changes at run time, whereas file has been uploaded as well.

Comment: what about using two inputs?